# Integral similar to a Laplace transform keeps blowing up.

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I'm working on a problem that results in the integral:
$$
\int_{x=0}^{x\rightarrow\infty}
x^{-1}e^{-xt}
\left[
v(x)
+
t
\int_{x'=x}^{x'\rightarrow\infty}
v(x')dx'
\right]
dx
$$
where $v(x)$ is a probability density function. The integrand without $x^{-1}$ is also a probability density function.  All of my attempts result in something that looks like $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\ln t$.  Also, the resemblance of the expression to the Laplace transform led me to something that had $t\mathscr L\{x^{-1}\}(t)$ which, as far as I can tell, also blows up.

All of this is frustrating because I believe the expression must converge based on the physics I've derived it from.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Unless the term in brackets goes to zero as $x\rightarrow 0$, this integral will diverge due to the $x^{-1}$ term. How did this integral come up?

Comment: The term $v(x)$ is a general distribution density, it does not need to go to zero.  The integral is $1-V(x)$ where $V(x)$ is the distribution function of $v(x)$.  So at $x=0$ the bracketed term is
$$ v + t\left[
1-(1+vx+\cdots)
\right]
=
v-txv-\cdots
$$
So as far as I can tell, if $v(x)$ goes to zero faster than $x^{-1}$ this thing _could_ converge.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the calculation that led to this integral or its physical motivation. That could help determine whether there is an error in the setup or if $v(x)$ necessarily goes to zero sufficiently fast.

Comment: The bracketed term comes from the solution of the equation
$$u_t=-xu+\int_{x'=x}^{x'\rightarrow\infty}u(x',t)dx'$$
with the initial condition
$$u(x,t=0)=v(x)$$
It physically corresponds to a particle size distribution $v(x)$ undergrowing fragmentation.